# EditorConfig: Allow or Enforce Private Fields to Begin with An Underscore

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, warnings, suppress-warnings, editorconfig

***EDIT:*** I'm using VS Code.

I'm getting the following warning for my code that prefixes private fields with an underscore:

```
Naming rule violation: Prefix '_' is not expected [MyProject]csharp(IDE1006)
```

Below is my code:

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class Dog
    {
        // Naming rule violation: Prefix '_' is not expected [MyProject]csharp(IDE1006)
        private int _age;

        public int Age()
        {
            return _age;
        }

        public void SetAge(int age)
        {
            _age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my `.editorconfig` file:

```
[*.cs]

# Require private fields to begin with an underscore (_).
dotnet_naming_rule.instance_fields_should_be_camel_case.severity = warning
dotnet_naming_rule.instance_fields_should_be_camel_case.symbols = instance_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.instance_fields_should_be_camel_case.style = instance_field_style
dotnet_naming_symbols.instance_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_style.instance_field_style.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style.instance_field_style.required_prefix = _
```

I'm also posting my `Directory.Build.props` file just in case it's conflicting with my `.editorconfig` file above.
I set it to be as strict as possible so I can fix (or suppress as needed) all warnings that a stricter C# compiler would raise:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Features>strict</Features>
    <WarningLevel>9999</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I'm looking for a solution where I can keep C#'s compiler as strict as possible and I can prefix private fields with an underscore, either by allowing them or preferably enforcing them (private fields ***without*** an underscore will get a warning).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally figured it out after studying Microsoft's documentation ***[here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules)***

Apparently, the middle section of an entry is an ***identifier*** and can be set to anything we want.

I have created a new rule that requires private fields to begin with an underscore and be in camel case.

Below is my new `.editorconfig` file:

```
# Define what we will treat as private fields.
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_fields.applicable_accessibilities = private
# Define rule that something must begin with an underscore and be in camel case.
dotnet_naming_style.require_underscore_prefix_and_camel_case.required_prefix = _
dotnet_naming_style.require_underscore_prefix_and_camel_case.capitalization = camel_case
# Appy our rule to private fields.
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_must_begin_with_underscore_and_be_in_camel_case.symbols = private_fields
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_must_begin_with_underscore_and_be_in_camel_case.style = require_underscore_prefix_and_camel_case
dotnet_naming_rule.private_fields_must_begin_with_underscore_and_be_in_camel_case.severity = warning
```

Many thanks to all those who helped, and I hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: This produces warnings also to the `static` and `const` fields.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio you can do this by going to options, then execute the following steps:

1. Go to "Naming" under C#
2. Click "Manage naming styles"
3. Click the + sign
4. Fill out a logical name
5. Fill "Required Prefix" with _
6. Select "Camel Case Name" for Capitalization
7. Click OK
8. Click OK
9. Click the + sign
10. Select "Private or Internal Field" (if you want private only you need to create a custom specification) as Specification
11. Select your custom naming style as naming style
12. Select Warning as severity

Keep in mind these setting will be overwritten by .editorconfig

Comment: My apologies, as I forgot to mention that I'm using VS Code. I have edited the OP. Is there a way to do the same for `.editorconfig` itself?

Comment: It should be possible to get the same result with ```.editorconfig``` but i'm not sure how.

Comment: I finally figured it out! Posted an Answer below and wanted to thank you for encouraging me that it's indeed possible even with just an `.editorconfig` file. :)